# Creating a neural network

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, backpropagation

I am creating a very simple neural network in python. What I ask for though is not any specific code but the general idea of how it works.
I understand about the inputs, weights and so on, everything in forward propagation.
What I do not understand is the back propagation. It compares the output to the desired output and calculates the error (difference) but how does it change all of the weights to be correct? Especially how can you change the weights to be different (not all be the same)?

Secondly, when you are changing the weights, how do you make it work for multiple inputs rather than just one input or the other?

Finally, what does the bias do and how do you decide what it is? I have heard it is added to the node it is connected to but in the scenario of 1 input, 1 output and 1 bias connected to the output:

Input is 0
Weight between input and output is -17.2
Bias is -1.79
Output is 0.9999999692839459

But how? 0 x -17.2 - 1.79 = -1.79??? That is not 1?

Thanks for your help everyone :)

Edit: Please do not give me links to other sources (e.g. not on stack overflow) because a good answer would help me and anyone reading this more. Thanks!

Comment: The short answer to the first question would be gradients. To the second one would be "you don't; the optimization in each step is for a particular sample". The long answer to both is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vq2nnJ4g6N0 and comes highly recommended

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a **book**, **tool**, **software library**, **tutorial** or other **off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would you be able to post this as an answer with an example? E.g. if the inputs are 1 and 2 then it will do this then give this output. The error is 4 so it will change this... @Ev.Kounis

Comment: @pedrolobito I was not asking for off site resources but an answer to my question. Ev.kounis game me a resource and I have asked for it to be changed into an answer

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld Writing the math here will take me more than you need to watch the video.

Comment: I agree @ev.kounis but it will be more useful for other people if they can see a straightforward written answer rather than watching a two hour video

Comment: This sounds like a "teach me how neural networks work" question. If you know how linear/logistic regression work, then you basically know how neural nets work. Neural networks (in their simplest form) are just generalized linear models.

Comment: @Jon Hello Jon, I understand how the neural network works, just not how the linear/logistic regression works. I just don't get how it changes the weights **_individually_** to match two **_different input sets_**. Hopefully this has made it clearer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at lineare regression trained by gradient descent. The goal of linear regression is to find a line (for the case of `R^1`), a linear function, that minimizes the least-squares-difference between a given sample `A` of pairs `{(xi,yi),...,(xn,yn)}` and the linear function `f(x)`.

By definition, the function of a line is given by `f(x) = m*x + b` where `m` is the slope and `b` the intersect with the y-axis. The cost function, which represents the squared difference between the function and the sample is `c(X,Y)=1/2n*Sum_i_to_n(f(x_i) - y_i)^2` where `X` and `Y` are vectors from the sample `A`.

So how do we achieve this?

Well, it's an unconstrained optimization problem because we want to minimize `c(X,Y)` over all entries in the sample `A`. Oh, that's actually the same as with a neural network but the function `f(x)` is more complex with neural nets.

The algorithm we use to solve this optimization problem is gradient descent which is defined as

```
x_t+1= x_t - alpha*f'(x_t)
```

So the value of a parameter `x` at time `t+1` is the the value of this parameter at time `t` plus some value of `alpha > 0`, which is often called the step size, times the partial derivative of `c(X,Y)` in respect to `x`.

In case of linear regression, our parameters are `m` and `b`. In case of a neural net, the parameters are the weights. That's because we want to learn a function that satisfies our goal of minimizing the squared-difference between our function's output and the training input.

For the intuition: The gradient, the vector of partial derivatives of a function, is always pointing to the direction of the steepest ascent of the functions surface. But since we want to minimize the function we want to go in the negative direction of the gradient. That way we go downward stepwise by the value of `alpha` while updating the values of our parameters with every step until we reach a minima. This is reached when the gradient `c'(X,Y)` is equal or almost equal to zero.

So in our example, we build the partial derivatives of `c(X,Y)` in respect to `m` and `b` and write a few lines of code to get it running.

As I said before, it's identical with the training/learing of a neural net. But with neural nets, we have a cascade of depending parameters. So, for example,  the weights of a hidden layer depends on the weights of the output layer during gradient descent. So you'll always have a cascade of partial derivaties. And that's where the chain rule is very useful.

Another difference between linear regression and neural nets is that the function `c(X,Y)` is non-convex with neural nets where it's convex with linear regression. That's because of the properties of the underlaying functions `f(x)`. Hence, when a function is convex, a local minima is always a global one. That's why you can never tell if you have an optimal solution with a neural net.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not the best at maths though, and I am having trouble figuring out what each of the letters represent. Would you be able to explain what each of the letters represent? If so that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Also I have made a slight edit to my question so if you know the answer please add that in as well :-)

Comment: Well, neural nets and machine learning topics are plain math :) The bias of a neural net is the same as the bias (b) of a line. Take a look at my example. At every layer, the neurons calculate the linear combination of the output of the previous layer times the associated weights plus some bias which is shared across a layer. The processing is similar to the function of a line in an higher dimensional space. Hence, it's an hyperplane. The result of that processing is afterwards put into an activation function to squash the neurons output to an specific interval e.g. (0,1). Does this help?

Comment: Btw: The bias is just like another weight which is shared across the layer. It's initially set to 1 and than trained by backpropagation  just like the other weights. Think of a line which is rotated within a space, but can't be moved up and down because it's y-intersection is fixed to 1....that wouldn't make much sense if you want to approximate all possible kinds of functions by a set of such lines, right?

Comment: Thanks this certainly does help. Two things i still don't get. [1] I still do not understand how it changes each weight individually to be correct. [2] How is 0*-17.2-1.79 equal to 0.9999999692839459?

Comment: Ask another question about this...but I explained why the weights are adjusted to a close to correct value .

Comment: Ok thanks. I will ask why it equals 0.9999999692839459. Also it says I can't ask another question

Comment: I need an up vote of 1 or more to be able to ask another question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142637/discussion-between-ruler-of-the-world-and-bastian-schoettle).